# ORA-04091 Error Keep two tables in sync using triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers, ora-04091

I need to keep two tables in a syc so when row inserted in Table A and one of column has certain condition then record should be added in table B. Also when row inserted in Table B then record should be added in Table A. How can this accomplish using Triggers. I had triggers for both tables After Insert but gives ORA-04091 error.

Answer (score 0):

Table is **mutating**, which means that you are selecting from it at the same time it is being affected by insert (or update). Since 11g, a **compound trigger** is the way out of it. In earlier Oracle versions (10g and lower) **package** has been used to deal with it.

However, mutating table frequently raises a question: are you doing it correctly? Maybe code you use can be rewritten so that error is avoided.

Finally, if those two tables contain the same data, why do you have two tables instead of one?

Comment: Second table has less columns then first and we want to use in new service but wanted to keep sync with old table.

Comment: These triggers fires in circular recursive fashion. Is there a way to stop?

Comment: Alter both tables and add a column which will be populated only by triggers. Include it into trigger's WHEN clause, e.g. `WHEN (new.cb_fire_trigger = 1)`. So, if some user inserts a row, make sure it enters `1` into the column so that trigger fires. Within the trigger, while inserting rows into another table, insert `0` into the column so that trigger on another table wouldn't fire and *copy* data back.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot for the information. I ended up using compound triggers with checking record exits for specific condition and then don't go further in trigger to avoid circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Use compound triggers with checking if record exits for specific condition and then don't go further in trigger to avoid circular dependency.